# Cannot resolve method setCookieHandler (java.net.CookieManger

Tags: java, okhttp, android-cookiemanager

I using CookieManger with okHttp and i don't know why its saying:

> Cannot resolve setCookieMethod.  I googled its a valid method and the
>   CookieManger and OkHttp is Imported in the project.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);        
client.setCookieHandler(cookieManager);
```

Comment: Try to set `CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);` after the cookieManager initialization.

Comment: Is this message being thrown by your IDE. Its possible that you are user older version of the library that doesn't have the method

Answer (score 4):

OkHttp has a new `CookieJar` interface!

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.cookieJar(cookieJar);
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
```

where `cookieJar` is an instance of `okhttp3.CookieJar`.

If you really like `java.net.CookieManager`, you can use Jesse's `JavaNetCookieJar`:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/java/okhttp3/JavaNetCookieJar.java

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieJar cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.cookieJar(cookieJar);
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
```

Comment: For the gradle dependencies, one can add the following:
`compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'` and `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.1.2'`

Comment: @MoonyChou Yeah, or you can remove the urlconnection dependency and just copy-paste only the `JavaNetCookieJar` if that's all you need.